# RegEx for google event

Tags: regex-group

Hello I would like help writing a regex that captures all urls with the word confirmation in it.

Ex:
https://example.com/this-is-a-confirmation

https://example.com/confirmation

https://example.com/folder/this-is-confirmation

I am trying to set up a Goal that captures all visits to any confirmation page on the website as by visiting that page you most likely filled out a form to download an asset

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, basically all links end with confirmation?

Then you could just use a very stupid and simple regex like:

```
confirmation$
```

If you only want the URL to contain confirmation:

```
confirmation
```

is already enough ([Demo](http://regexr.com/5r6g5)). That's basically the same as if you were using `String.endsWith(str)` and `String.contains(str)`.

Depending on the way you're evaluating this, you may need to allow chars before the search term to produce a full match (not only a partial match):

```
.*confirmation
```

or

```
.*confirmation.*
```

if you want to allow any text after the search term.

Comment: Thank you for your help @maio290!